# Order an array of objects by whether property exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of teachers, where each one have a property `user` with `image` property, that can contain a `string` or `null` value.
How can i order the array, considering the `user.image` property?

Here is an example of structure.

```
const teachers = [
    {
        id: 1,
        user: {
            id: 10,
            image: "image.jgp"
        }
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        user: {
            id: 30,
            image: null
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        user: {
            id: 20,
            image: "image.jgp"
        }
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        user: {
            id: 40,
            image: null
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: What should their order be? There's only two values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Comment: The order should be, first all objects which `user.image` is a string, and, all which `user.image` is null, in the final. The array is just a example and the structure just have the basic to explain the problem.

Comment: It's a matter of writing a sort function, which compares two elements from your array. In your case, it would be something like `(a, b) => a.user.image.localeCompare(b.user.image)`. I wrote about comparing objects: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/supercharged-sorts-in-javascript/

Comment: It doesn't, because i just mind if are a value, not the unicode o value

Comment: @Snowmonkey `localeCompare` doesn’t exist on `null`.

Comment: Could get funky: `(a,b)=>Number(Boolean(a.user.image))-Number(Boolean(b.user.image))` a null would be zero, any string would be one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and check whether the `image` property is `null`:

```js
const teachers=[{id:1,user:{id:10,image:"image.jgp"}},{id:3,user:{id:30,image:null}},{id:2,user:{id:20,image:"image.jgp"}},{id:4,user:{id:40,image:null}}];

const sorted = teachers.sort((a, b) => b.user.image === null ? -1 : 1)

console.log(sorted)
```